# Post selected rows with jquery to a Django 1.5 view

Tags: ajax, django, post, view, selectable

I have a table with multiple `<tr>` which each has a PK as ID. I am going to POST these `<tr>` to a Django 1.5 view, but I don't know how to send the data properly.

I've made this javascript function, and it posts successfully, but I don't know how to send the id's of selected_rows, and how to retrieve them in a class based Django view.

```
function update() {
    var selected_rows = $(".ui-selected");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/confirm/",
        data: { name: "selected_rows" },
        success: function(data) {
            selected_rows.addClass('success');
        }
    });
}
```

I guess the Django view is something like

```
class ConfirmView(TemplateView):
    def post(self, queryset=None):
        return HttpResponse("POST")
```

I've also tried

```
function update() {
    var selected_rows = $(".ui-selected");
        selected_rows.each(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/confirm/",
            data: { id: $(this).attr("id") },
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).addClass('success');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
class ConfirmView(TemplateView):
    def post(self, queryset=None):
        if self.request.POST['id']:
            ModelName.objects.filter(pk=self.request.POST['id']).update(is_confirmed=True)
        return HttpResponse("POST")
```

But I guess it's better to handle all the rows in the same database query instead of splitting them as above. But if I split them as above, I could check whether or not they were updated successfully, so maybe it's better that way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
data: { name: selected_rows }  //Do not put selected_rows in quotes
```

Also why are you using TemplateView here, it doesn't give you any advantage. You just need to create something and send a response which ajax will handle. You can just use a function view here.

If you use class based view, your signature of `post` has a bug:

It should be:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    name = request.POST['name']
```